# How to display the data of objects saved in localStorage on the front-end? Goal: display products added by unregistered users to favorites

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Hi guys I need some help with javascript. For the second day, I have been trying to make a functional: a page with selected models for unregistered users. Details: there is a page with models (products), the user clicks the "add to favorites" button, and the product is displayed on the favorites page for unregistered users. I tried to implement this in several ways but settled on local storage. And here's what I've got so far:

```
/*** Add to Favorite non-register ***/

 const nonRegister = document.querySelectorAll('.non-register');
   nonRegister.forEach(item=>{

  item.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let modelId = item.getAttribute('model-id');
    let modelTitle = item.getAttribute('model-title');
    let modelPicture = item.getAttribute('model-image');
    let modelLink = item.getAttribute('model-link');

    /*** I use this part to check that there are no duplicates ***/

    let myFavoriteArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favoriteItems") || "[]");
    let retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("favoriteItems");
    let retrievedDataArray = JSON.parse(retrievedData);

    alert(modelId)
    if(retrievedDataArray !== null && retrievedDataArray.includes(modelId)){
        alert('This model has already been added to favorites')
    }else{
        /*** for checking ***/
        myFavoriteArray.push(modelId);
        localStorage.setItem("favoriteItems", JSON.stringify(myFavoriteArray));

        /*** Function creates an array with objects the user has added to favorites. ***/

        let modelObject = {
            'modelId':  modelId,
            'modelTitle':  modelTitle,
            'modelPicture': modelPicture,
            'modelLink': modelLink,
        }

        let oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsArray')) || [];
        oldItems.push(modelObject);
        localStorage.setItem('itemsArray', JSON.stringify(oldItems));
    }
   });
});

/*** Add to Favorite non-register END ***/
```

And everything is good up to this point. But then my knowledge is not enough. If I add some items to favorites and execute this code:

```
let itemsArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsArray'));
itemsArray.forEach(item => console.log(item));
```

The console will display a nice answer:

[![this is what is displayed in the console][1]][1]

But how can I bring this to the front-end? To display it as in the example:

[![this is what I need to display on the frontend][2]][2]

I work more with PHP so I'm just confused. Because what was obvious to me in the case of PHP (when I did the same functionality for registered users) is not obvious now. How can I loop out data from local storage to the front end? Please help me figure this out.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA0GV.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6vId.png

Comment: Here, you add the pictures to the localStorage (favorites), but where do you fetch them to be displayed?

Comment: @nimeresam I get it from here: 

<div model-link="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" model-image="<?php echo $url; ?>" model-title="<?php the_title(); ?>" model-id="<?php $model_id = the_ID(); ?>" class="non-register"> <span><i class="far fa-heart"></i></span></div>

from the atributs model-image="<?php echo $url; ?>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out this issue!

Here is the result:

```
let itemsArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsArray'));
let finalHtml = "";
let modLink;
let modTitle;
let modImage;

for (var item in itemsArray) {
     modImage +=
    '<div class="single-project__model-wrapper">  <div id="favorite__loop-unregister" 
     class="single-project__model">  <div class="single-project__model-item">'
    +'<a class="single-project__model-item_favorite" href="#"><img src="/wp- 
      content/themes/aleyra/images/remove.svg" alt="add_to_favorite"></a>'
    +'<a class="single-project__model-item_content" href="#">'
    +'<div class="single-project__model-item_content-img">'
    +'<img src="'+ itemsArray[item].modelPicture +'" alt="collection-img">'+
    '</div>'+
    '</a>'+
    '</div> </div> </div>';
     document.getElementById("favorite__loop-unregister").innerHTML = modImage;
 }
```

Perhaps this is not the really elegant solution. But I'm not a nija of JavaScript, I'm just a humble WordPress/PHP developer. If someone has a desire to refactor the code, I would be grateful. But so far this option works for me.